# How to keep scanning for BLE sensors and Identify sensor keyEvent while iOS App is terminated

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

How to keep scanning for BLE Sensors while App is in the terminated status in IOS App. While App is running I am able to manage multiple sensors. However, when App is terminated, how to keep listening to an advertisement and connect the Sensor to App not running status.

**State preservation and State Restoration** is implemented. Background mode **Bluetooth-Central** is turned on

I want to achieve it like Tile and Chipolo are doing in the terminate state.

Comment: Turn on bluetooth capabilities from background mode(select target file).

Comment: Background mode is already turned on. Also using Restore Identifier
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : Any]).

Comment: By terminated, do you mean force-quit, or just backgrounded and _maybe_ terminated because it was in the background for a while?

Comment: Terminated by user explicitly. i.e Force-Quit Using task switcher

Comment: As far as I know, iOS does not restart apps in the background after they've been forcibly killed by the user. See "Understanding When Your App Gets Launched into the Background" here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html: _In most cases, the system does not relaunch apps after they are force quit by the user._

Comment: Yes, However, I have seen how it has been already implemented by someone. Please watch this video for the reference. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yXrfi0EmfqA

Comment: Hey any one have solution if App terminated forcefully by system or user can we connect or scan new peripheral devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible with normal ble capabilities:

> Apps that support background execution may be relaunched by the system to handle incoming events. If an app is terminated for any reason other than the user force quitting it, the system launches the app when one of the following events happens:

Refer to [Understanding When Your App Gets Launched into the Background](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW7)

The way tile works is by using the iBeacon standard (my best guess).

An iBeacon is substantially a BLE. Your app can start a [Region Monitoring for an iBeacon](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html) receiving region events (enter, exit). These events would wake your app also if the user killed it. When your app is awaken by a region enter event you have 8 seconds (give or take) to execute code and react to the event. Within this time you can start a standard BLE connection to use your iBeacon as peripheral and keep your app reactive to BLE events.

Of course your peripheral must be designed to support such behaviour.

Comment: Agree with you. I have tried each possible way to achieve it using BLE. Found via logs that App did woke up in the background, but it was initiated by IOS. If user terminated app. It does not wakeup. 
I had seen Chipolo sending in Range, out of range notifications which only comes when we use region monitoring methods of CLLocationManager. I have tested this with my app by creating virtual beacon on another phone. Then Monitoring this virtual beacon in my app. I am able to get near, far notifications in the foreground and background. Tried to kill app at this time. Still App did not woke up.

Comment: I'm positive about the fact that with iBeacon the thing works properly. Make sure that you are actually getting out of the region and moving in again for the notification to start. Near far notifications are for proximity monitoring. Region monitoring should give you notifications relative to enter/exit from the beacon area.

Comment: As explained in the medium post. We must design our hardware in such a way that when user force quite iOS App it should advertise as iBeacon. 

https://medium.com/arkulpa/ios-stay-connected-to-an-external-ble-device-as-much-as-possible-699d434846d2.

Comment: Hey any one have solution if App terminated forcefully by system or user can we connect or scan new peripheral devices?